# Google Sheets Web App returns value in A1 instead of Active Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have the below web app to attach files into a specific cell in Google Sheets.

Web app is uploading files in Google Drive, then adding the link to the cell in Google Sheets.

All is good except that **the link is always being added to A1 cell only**, not the active cell.

I tried getCurrentCell() instead of getActiveCell() as well but the same result.

Any solution? Thanks

**Code.gs**

```
// new property service GLOBAL
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/


function setup() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  
  
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId()); //SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key");
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("expenses_folderid","1f8jX4SSceIkPDQxVFvrq3X"); //SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("expenses_folderid") 
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("webappurl","https://script.google.com/a/macros/talabat.com/s/AKfycbzEuUW_0sK0tHbOohdWBJv1OyEYzDwerHimosmO8SWxicpu4/exec"); //SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("webappurl")
    
}


function doPost(e) {

  try {
    
       var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
       var filename = e.parameter.filename;
       var newfilename = filename;
       var result=uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,newfilename,e); 
     
  } 
  catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,newfilename,e) {
  try {
    
    folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("expenses_folderid"));
    var newupdatedfilename = newfilename;
    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, newupdatedfilename);
        var file = folder.createFile(blob);
        var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
           
    record_data(e,fileUrl);
    
    
  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}



function doGet(e){}


function onOpen(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Attach", functionName: "doMenu1"});
  ss.addMenu("RM Attachments", menuEntries);
}

function doMenu1(e) {
  
  
  //var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('upload');
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File '+SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("quartername"));
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('upload');
  tmp.webappurl = SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("webappurl");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(tmp.evaluate(), 'Attach');
  
}

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
  

  var value = fileUrl
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  
  
   cell.setValue(value);
}
```

**upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Style The Form How Ever You Prefer -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleresponsive.css">  -->
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.form-inline {  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-inline label {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}

.form-inline input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.form-inline button {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-inline button:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .form-inline input {
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
  
  .form-inline {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>


<!--<h2>Responsive Inline Form</h2>-->

<form class="form-inline" id="form" action="<?= webappurl; ?>" target="my-iframe" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="filetype" id="filetype">
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileextensionfield" id="fileextensionfield">
  
  
  
            
              
            
             
            
        
             <input type="hidden" value="" name="skillsets" id="skillsets">
             <input type="hidden" value="" name="linkedinUrl" id="linkedinUrl">   
             
         
</form>
<iframe name="my-iframe" src="<?= webappurl; ?>" style="display: none;" onload="changed()" ></iframe>
<p></p>
<label> Attach:<span style="color: red;">*</span>&nbsp;</label><input id="attach" name="attach" type="file"/>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" />


<script type="text/javascript">

  
 
 function getFileExtension(fullfilename) {
        return fullfilename.substring(fullfilename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, fullfilename.length) || fullfilename;
  }


var progressbar = document.createElement("PROGRESS");
progressbar.setAttribute("value", "0");
progressbar.setAttribute("max", "100");
document.body.appendChild(progressbar);
var progressbar_element = document.getElementsByTagName("PROGRESS");
progressbar_element[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
console.log('progress bar complete');

  
  

var change_count = 0; //used to see when the google apps script iframe has changed , letting you know the file has been uploaded.
function changed() {



    if (change_count === 1 /* NUMBER OF TIMES IFRAME IS LOADED */) {
        setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "92") }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "95") }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "97") }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "100") }, 100);
        console.log('iframe source has changed: ', change_count);
        
        //setTimeout(function(){alert('File Upload Completed')}, 200);
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('displaygreen').innerHTML = 
                    'File uploaded successfully.';}, 200);
        //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
         //           'File uploaded successfully.';
        
        document.getElementById('attach').value= null;
        document.getElementById("form").reset()
        
        setTimeout(function(){
        progressbar.setAttribute("value", "0");
        progressbar_element[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }, 2000);
        
        
        
    }
    else {

        window.change_count += 1;

    }
}

      console.log(' First part of page load complete');




function UploadFile() {

document.getElementById('displaygreen').innerHTML = ""
document.getElementById('displayred').innerHTML = ""



//Check required fields




if( document.getElementById("attach").files.length == 0 ){
    //alert("No file selected");
    document.getElementById('displayred').innerHTML = "Please choose a file to upload.";
    return false;
}




  document.getElementById('displayred').innerHTML = "";

  progressbar_element[0].style.visibility = 'visible';

  progressbar.setAttribute("value", "22");
 
 


  var reader = new FileReader();
  var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
  
  var fileextension = getFileExtension(file.name);
  console.log('file extension: ', fileextension);
        
  
  
  reader.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
    document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
    document.getElementById('filetype').value=file.type;
    document.getElementById('fileextensionfield').value=fileextension;
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
    }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  
  setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "30") }, 500);
  setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "50") }, 500);
  setTimeout(function(){progressbar.setAttribute("value", "80") }, 500);    
  

  
}

</script>

<p><span id='displaygreen' style="color:#008000"></span></p>
<p><span id='displayred' style="color:#FF0000"></span></p>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In the `doGet()` context, you cannot find if some user somewhere in the world has the spreadsheet open, nor which sheet and cell they currently happen to have active.

One way to make the active sheet and cell available would be to recast your [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) as a [container-bound script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) or an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons). Bound scripts and add-ons have the spreadsheet and user context, while web apps only have the user context (or the developer user context).

Bound scripts and add-ons are essentially the same implementation-wise, but a bound script is much easier to *deploy*. The drawbacks of a bound script are that the every user will have to go through the script authorization flow the first time they start the script, and users also get edit access to the source code. Add-ons also require authorization, but the source code is not revealed.

The user interface would have to be shown in a sidebar or a dialog box. The UI code would probably not need too many changes, but client-server communication would have to be done with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) instead of `doPost()`.

If you cannot implement your code as an add-on, you can append the URL to the first blank row of the first sheet, like this:

```
function record_data(e, fileUrl) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow([fileUrl]);
}
```

Use [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to use another sheet instead of the first sheet.

Comment: So there is no way to append the URL to the active cell? Web app already recognizing the sheet and appending the URL, but always in cell A1. I want it to be appended to the active cell.

Comment: Apps Script runs in Google's servers, not in your browser. In the `doGet()` context, you cannot find if some user somewhere in the world has the spreadsheet open, nor which sheet and cell they currently happen to have active.

Comment: Don't see how addons would be able to help here. Did you mean letting go off the web app and providing the ui in the sidebar?

Comment: So you don't mean "add-on" specifically right? You  just meant "sidebar" with a bound script.

Comment: Yes... it is unclear why the OP is using a web app in the first place. My assumption has been that it is to avoid granting end-users edit access to the source code. Edited the answer.